# Is it possible to compare an asp.net hash+salt against the HIBP database?

Tags: cryptography, passwords

I have a website that uses default asp.net security to authenticate users and a table with password hashes and salts.  Is it possible to compare these against the hashed passwords from the haveibeenpwned.com database?

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

You can't do this by hitting the database directly, because you need to have the plaintext string in order to get the right hash to perform the lookup.

But you could approach it a different way - by cracking your existing salted hashes, using [the cracked corpora of the HIBP data from hashes.org](https://hashes.org/leaks.php). This is not generally advisable in most circumstances, though.

You could also set it up to check it in circumstances where you already have the plaintext in hand - whenever users sign up, log in and/or change their password, etc. A general blacklist of the top X well-known passwords is generally a good idea - but I don't recommend using the entire 512 million passwords as a blacklist *for new password creation* without significant additional UX guidance on how to create good passwords (with Diceware-style randomly generated passphrases, or randomly generated strings stored in a password manager, etc.)